# Trying to show room information in Autodesk Forge / Bim360

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit-api, autodesk-bim360

Okay so, I'm trying to show room information and geometry from a Revit project on Forge. I've made the call to `https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/jobs` with `Setting advanced/generateMasterViews field to true`, yet, even if I get a correct response, and even from `https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/:urn/manifest` I get that the model is successfully translated but still, no room information. I've looked in Forge for the room information with no luck. Afterwards I've tried to publish it to Bim360 knowing that B360 automatically gets the room information and geometry. And for a moment it looked like it worked. The model displayed the rooms and the information
:
[image]

So, I close B360 and try after a few seconds I open it again and... :
[image]

No geometry, no room information. Nothing. Maybe is something wrong with the model? I've tried deleting and recreating the rooms in revit, modifying the Publish settings etc but this isn't my job, I only have basic notions as I'm a programmer. Anything?

*EDIT : After further tries, I've noticed after every model update on B360 I get room geometry on the first open. Only the first time I open it.

Comment: To load room meshes with Forge viewer, you need to specify `skipHiddenFragments: false` while calling `Viewer3D#loadDocumentNode`. See here for example: https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-bim360-assets.viewer#troubleshooting

Comment: The question was for forge viewer but i actually solved it! Im going to write a response right now!

Comment: Thanks for the updates and sharing. Originally, I thought that the root cause of missing room meshes might be that hidden objects are not loaded by the viewer while loading models in the SVF2(OTG) format as I know. BIM360 is using SVF2(OTG). Glad to hear it's not the case. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so I've solved it. I'ts was not a forge nor B360 error, it was an error on the model! The problem was Revit was not generating volume for the rooms because It was told not to!
I actually had Revit Area and Volume Computations on Areas only (which is faster, but doesn't generate volumes for rooms) To change this i just had to :

1.
[image]

2.

[image]

Then click OK and save the model. Afterwards you have to upload the file and translate it by using generateMasterViews! And done! You'll have your master view with room geometry.