# Autodesk Forge Viewer : Room volumes not visible when using SVF2

Tags: autodesk-viewer

When I try to load the SVF2 environments for a SVF2 converted BIM model in the viewer, the rooms don't appear.

SVF 2 Image :  [SVF2 Viewer with rooms unhidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbWL9.png)
SVF Image : [Viewer that has room volumes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jChBP.png)

Applied the skipHiddenFragments:False : [SVF2 With Fragment Override](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MR41y.png)

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of reasons that might cause this behavior.

1. For Revit, only the master views have room geometries, so you need to load master views in Forge Viewer to see rooms.

```js
// Method 1
bubbleNode.getDefaultGeometry(true); //!<<< get first master view
// ref: https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-dataviz-iot-react-components/blob/main/client/components/Viewer.jsx#L156

// Method 2
const root = viewerDocument.getRoot();
const viewables = root.search({'type':'geometry', 'role': '3d'});
console.log('Viewables:', viewables);
const phaseViews = viewables.filter(v => v.data.name === v.data.phaseNames && v.getViewableRootPath().includes('08f99ae5-b8be-4f8d-881b-128675723c10'));
console.log('Master Views:', phaseViews);
```

2. Before viewer `v7.52`, Rooms are hidden by default when loading the SVF2 view with Forge Viewer. To make Rooms visible, you need to set `skipHiddenFragments: false` to `viewer.loadDocumentNode`

```js
await this.viewer.loadDocumentNode(
    doc,
    masterViewBubble,
    {
        skipHiddenFragments: false
    }
);
```

**Update Sept. 17:** With `v7.52` and the later versions, we just need to be sure to load the master view bubble to see rooms of Revit.

```js
await this.viewer.loadDocumentNode(
    doc,
    masterViewBubble
);
```

ref: https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-bim360-assets.viewer#troubleshooting

3. The `Revit Area and Volume Computations` is not `Areas and Volumes`:   https://stackoverflow.com/a/67775385/7745569

Comment: Thank you Eason Kang for your response but I should have added that when the same model and code is loaded using the SVF environment, works just fine and room volumes are seen. In the SVF2 env the rooms are loaded in the viewer and can be seen as unhidden in the model browser.
It could be the third solution that is causing this issue but still confused as to why it would work in an SVF env then..
I have edited the original post to have images of what I'm trying to say

Comment: @jash,  the `skipHiddenFragments` value is false by default for SVF, but this value is true for SVF2. So, you need to set `skipHiddenFragments` to false when viewing with SVF2.

Comment: Again appreciate the quick response but I did try that but still no luck. We can see the model name was overriden and I didn't get any errors so I assume the skipHiddenFragments to false also worked but I still can't see room volumes... 
I have attached a screenshot with the original post called "SVF2 With Fragment Override".
Thank you

Comment: Could you consider providing a non-confidential reproducible model demonstrating this issue to `forge[DOT]help[AT]autodesk[DOT]com`? Need to investigate the model and test from our side to see what happened. Otherwise, I run out of my idea ...